# iOS deployment issue of Ionic 3 app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I developed an application using Ionic 3.20.0 and I tried to release that in both play store and App Store. In play store, it is published and working fine for the users. On the other hand, in iOS, we installed and tried in our local devices and we could able to get the output. But when I upload in the App Store, they are rejecting the app by sending the below response

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 11.4.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network. After launch, app shows blank white page without functionality.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review. Please plan a resolution asap and resolve.

I've no clue on where I did mistake. Will this be build issue or network issue?

I'll share my config.xml also for reference.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.sample.app" version="1.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <description>XYZ</description>
    <author email="aa@aa.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Developer </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="1200000" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://10.0.0.27:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.60.29:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.60.57:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.137.1:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.70.104:8100" />
    <engine name="windows" spec="5.0.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="6.4.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="^7.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-otp-auto-verification" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="^1.8.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-sms" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-apprate" spec="~1.3.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

First run your application in your real device from Xcode open device console and there you might have some issue fix it. If your app is in under review run your application using testFlight. You can find your problem yourself. I also faced that same issue i found my problem through testFlight App.